# How to run cronjobs in WordPress on docker

Tags: cron, curl, docker

I am running a WordPress site in a docker container.  The site works but the cronjobs do not run so I downloaded crontrol to get a GUI into crontab so I could confirm that the jobs existed and I see this when I load the page above the list of jobs:
[image]

an error saying that my site can't run cronjobs.  How do I run my jobs?

(btw I can run curl commands from my container)

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
   db:
     platform: linux/x86_64
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     ports:
       - "3309:3306"
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
       MYSQL_DATABASE: forumator

   redis:
     image: redis:5.0.4
     # command: ["redis-server", "--appendonly", "yes"]
     hostname: redis
     restart: always
     ports:
      - 6379:6379
     volumes:
      - redis-data:/data

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
       - redis
     links:
       - redis
     build:
       context: ./
       dockerfile: ./.docker/Dockerfile
     working_dir: /var/www/html
     volumes:
       - ./:/var/www/html/wp-content
     ports:
       - "80:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: forumator
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: passw
       ENV: local
       WORDPRESS_DEBUG: 0
       WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |
        define( 'SBDAPI_AUTH', 'webdev@forumator.org:secret?' );
        $$redis_server = [
          'host' => 'redis',
          'port' => 6379,
          'auth' => '',
          'database' => 0
        ];

volumes:
    db_data:
    redis-data:
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM wordpress:6.1.1-php7.4

RUN yes '' | pecl install redis
RUN docker-php-ext-enable redis
```

Comment: the cronjob configuration works on real servers, so it's either my docker container or WP Cronjobs are just buggy on docker containers...

Comment: Hi Steve, you found any solutions on this? running cronjobs inside the docker image?

Comment: @caramba I wish lol, my answer so far is poorly but sometimes they run buggily

Comment: Here's an example of a cron container that makes a network call: https://github.com/vast-project/socialmediaharvester/blob/master/docker-compose.yml#L64 , but what's the WP endpoint to run scheduled tasks?